# 24VAC Binary Encoder / Decoder for Sprinkler System

Tags: circuit-design, ac, encoder, binary, decoder

I have a typical sprinkler system that runs on 24VAC.

My sprinkler controller is in my garage and my sprinkler valves are across the yard with a cable running underground with 5 wires. One wire is the ground, and the other 4 wires run 24VAC to turn on each of the 4 valves.

The problem I have is that I want to add some more sprinkler valves over there but I don't want to dig another trench to run a cable and so I'm thinking about some alternative solutions.

One thing to note about sprinkler controllers is they are typically programmed so they never run two zones at the same time to ensure there is enough water pressure to operate.

And so in order to accommodate more zones, I'm thinking of using a binary encoder/decoder to allow be to trigger 16 separate valves using the 5-wire connection.

[image: encoder/decoder diagram]

I'm not super familiar with how to build circuits like this for AC current.

I thought about rectifying AC into DC and use the digital signal to trigger a relay, but then there's a problem on the decoder side of things because it needs to output 24VAC. So I think ideally this entire circuit would be 24VAC the whole time...

So my question: How would you build this circuit? Are there any off-the-shelf parts for this kind of thing? If you were to build this circuit from scratch, how would you do it? Can you build AND/OR logic gates for AC current?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: With a 5-conductor cable, you should be able to run valve AC power, ground, DC power for the control circuitry, and two control lines for serial communication.

Comment: That could work, with a microcontroller on each side. I guess I was hoping for something a little leaner...

Comment: use diodes to split the positive and negative cycles between two valves ... this may result in magnetized solenoids in the valves though ... you may need to reverse the diodes once in a while

Comment: At the very least you would still need to dig trenches to run the extra water lines and power lines to each new sprinkler valve.

Comment: Yes, but only from the closest set of valves, not all the way back to the controller